# In .NET, is it possible to set Events based on calling of a function

Tags: c#, .net, events, function, call

Say I have a function named:

```
void AFun()
{
// body
}
```

Is it possible to set an event whenever this function is called. Say,

```
void AnEvent()
{
//body
}
```

And `AnEvent()` will always be called whenever `AFun()` is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is, but indirectly, if you emit an event in AFun, and AnEvent will listen to that event you'll achieve what you want. Otherwise what  you describe is not directly supported

Code sample:

```
public delegate void EventHandler();
public event EventHandler ev;

public void AFun
{
   ...do stuff
   ev(); //emit
}

//somewhere in the ctor
ev += MyEventHandler;

//finally 

void MyEventHandler
{
    //handle the event
}
```

Comment: could you please give code snippet or resources with examples on how to set them.

Comment: @Gunner, declaring events and raising them and listening to them is quite elementary C#/.NET.  Please consult your favorite introductory book on C#.

Comment: I was hoping if it was possible to do so without modifying AFun, that is do the assigning from elsewhere.

Comment: @Gunner: No, as I mentioned in my answer, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Easy Way:

```
event EventHandler AnEventHappened;

void AFun()
{
   OnAnEvent();
}

void AnEvent()
{

}

void OnAnEvent()
{
  var tmp = AnEventHappened;
  if(tmp != null) tmp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: That will not compile, will it? (I guess it will fail with a message along the lines of "unable to convert from EventHandler to Boolean")

Comment: @Fred: sorry - too much javascript. Meant to test for null.

Answer (score 1):

Not as you write it.  What you describe is called "Aspect-Oriented Programming" (AOP) and requires compiler support.

Now, there are some extensions to C# and .NET that does AOP by injecting listeners and events into the right places in the code.

Off-topic: in JavaScript you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Hard Way:

Use Aspect Oriented Programming (with something like Castle, or PostSharp) and emit the event that way.